# Use query to query different table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

im new in sql query,

and i have problem here..

how i can use query to query with different table?

```
Table member_list          Table member_history
+-----------+--------+     +-----------+--------+
| member_id | gender |     | member_id | spend  |
+-----------+--------+     +-----------+--------+
| 1         | 1      |     | 1         | 100    |
| 2         | 2      |     | 2         | 150    |
| 3         | 1      |     | 1         | 75     |
+-----------+--------+     | 3         | 240    |
                           | 1         | 290    |
                           +-----------+--------+

$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member_list where gender = 1");
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT spend FROM member_history WHERE spend < 250");
```

from above query $query1 will result member_id : 1,3 and $query2 will result 1(100),2(150),1(75),3(240)

my question is:

1. how i can get $query2 only show 1,3 not 1,2,1,3? or how i can check result from $query1 on $query2 so i can get $query2 will result 1,3 not 1,2,1,3?

anyone can help me?
sorry if my english not good.

Comment: It's a perfect scenario for `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM member_list ml join member_history mh
on ml.member_id=mh.member_id
where gender = 1 and spend < 250
```

Comment: ooww.. this is awesome. so simple. goodjob sir. i learn much from you. thanks again.